# In Drupal, how do I link two taxonomies?

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I'm trying to have an athlete (which is a content type) be assigned a "sport" and a "team".  I'm trying to use taxonomies...not sure if this is the best or correct way to do it.  I originally had a hierarchical taxonomy, like

- Baseball

  - Chicago Cubs
  - Detroit Tigers
- Basketball

  - Denver Nuggets
  - Utah Jazz

But that doesn't seem right because the Cubs aren't a type of baseball...the "athletes" view should be filterable by sport and then team with dynamic dropdowns, and the node should display both sport and team.  Is there a way to have to separate taxonomies that are linked?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**Edit:** Found a great module called Hierarchical Select, though it is not ported completely to Drupal 7.  I've had hint after hint that I should just go with Drupal 6 on this project.  Guess I'm going to go ahead and make the jump now, while it's still early.

P.S. So do I delete this question...or just leave it?

Comment: You can post an answer yourself and accept it as the answer to the question, so that it may be a help to others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go with the Hierarchical Select module.  It works very nicely.